# "时间过的好快" Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar

I found this sentence in a very short history ; 时间过的好快！, but i think maybe the person that wrote the sentence  made a mistake and change 得 for 的.
Cause in this case 得 should be used as a "verb complement" , and 的 don't have any posible meaning.
Is my assumption right ?

Comment: This is like the confusion about "its" and "it's" in English.  There is a clear "official" rule about when to use which form, but many people get it wrong.  When the new style of "Mandarin" first came into widespread use in the early 20th Century, usage was also more fluid.

Comment: Depends on which normative standards you are following. In Taiwan, 的, 地, and 得 are all merged into 的. Go and compare the dictionaries from both regions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think you are correct, as 得 is usually placed after verbs in order to signify the outcome of that verb or to modify it.

In general:

- 的 (de) for modifying nouns. It has two typical forms: "Noun + 的 + Noun" and "Adjective + 的 + Noun".
- 得 (de), for modifying verbs. It also has two forms: "Verb + 得 + Adjective" and "Adjective + 得 + Comparison word (ie more, less)".

See this [tutoring](http://blog.tutorming.com/mandarin-chinese-learning-tips/de-particles-in-chinese-grammar#:%7E:text=They%20are%20all%20pronounced%20%E2%80%9Cde%E2%80%9D%20with%20the%20neutral,of%20the%20most%20common%20grammar%20mistakes%20in%20Chinese.) for more explanations/examples.

Answer (score 5):

It's OK but ususally we will say "时间过得好快" since "过" is a verb.

Answer (score 3):

The correct sentence is 时间过得好快！(not 时间过的好快！)

The problem of 的  mistakenly replacing 地 has come up a lot. Since the pinyin of 的/de/ and 地/de/ are the same, people often mistakenly use 的 when they meant to use 地. For example, 重重的打击  (heavy hit) is not the same as 重重地打击 (heavily hit), but  we can often see someone write 重重的打击他 (heavy hit him) when he meant 重重地打擊他 (heavily hit him)

And now even the similar-sounding 得 /dé/ is mistakenly replaced by 的/de/ on writing

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of saying it is "时间过得好快“ or "时间过得很快“；so it's "得“ instead of "的". Yes, "得“ is used to link the verbs or adjectives to adverbs. "的" has a meaning as well, it's a possessive particle and is used with nouns.

It's easy to make a mistake and use the wrong "de" out of three "地", "的" "得". I sometimes use "得" instead of "地" and vice versa.

You can find more information about the difference between the three "de" and maybe some examples. [here](https://www.nihaocafe.com/how-to-use-de-%E7%9A%84-%E5%9C%B0-or-%E5%BE%97/) Hope it helps.